# How to get source value affected to a constant using C# reflection

Tags: c#

Here is my problem:

I have a class A(from project A) referencing class B(from project B). Each project is built to its own assembly

```
 public class B
{
   public const string CONSTANT_B= "Anything";

}


public class A
{
  public const string filedA = B.CONSTANT_B;

}
```

I need to get fieldA from A class and verify if its value comes from another class(here class B).

I did this :

```
 var fieldInfo = typeof(A).GetFields(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public)[0];
 var value = fieldInfo.GetValue(BindingFlags.Default);
```

The result was: 'Anything'

So how please can I get B.CONSTANT_B instead? or just to know if Class A needs reference to class B.

My goal is to remove the reference to project B if it's unused by the project A.
So how can I decide to remove It or to keep It?
FYI: I have both source code and binaries of these projects.

Comment: This information is likely not available at runtime, particularly if both these classes are in the same assembly. One of the optimizations the compiler might apply is to copy the value of `CONSTANT_B` into `A`. Whether this is done cross-assembly, I don't know for certain. Even if it is not, the only place the refernce to `B` would appear would be in the static initializer for `A`. Obtaining this info would involve disassembling its IL code.

Comment: Yes the compiler will use the value from the constant, even across assemblies. The idea being if it's truly "constant" then it can use the value as it _should_ never change.  If it may change over time then `constant` is not appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how please can I get B.CONSTANT_B instead?

You can't When you build project A the *value* for the field is read from the constant field of clas B and baked directly into the code. There is no metadata to query or IL to disassemble that would tell you that the value came from `B.CONSTANT_B`.

The only way that you can verify that class A gets the constant from class B is by looking at the source code.

Note also that if you change the value of `B.CONSTANT_B` then that change is NOT reflected in class A unless you *rebuild* the project.

Now if both fields were `readonly` instead of `constant` you could possibly disassemble the IL to see if project A references the read-only field in B, but it would still not be available via reflection.

Comment: Very nice answer since it includes a simple way to prove the answer

Comment: Thank you @D Stanley for your unswer. Do you please have an idea how can I verify that class A needs to reference class B using source code(I want to do this programmatically)